# UIView: additionalLayoutSupport nsis_valueOfVariable:didChangeInEngine issue after huge increase for memory warning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My memory usage increase up to 3GB and then crashes with the following info reported to TestFlight:

[image]

How can I debug it in code? What can I do to resolve this? I have no idea where should I look it for.

In code it happens when user taps on UICollectionViewCell:

```
func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt _: IndexPath) {
    let controller = UIViewController()
    controller.view.backgroundColor = .orange
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

With this code, after tap, memory usage increase 70mb per every second up to 3GB and then crash with memory warning. Why? What may happen here?

### Edit

I think I know where is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Within my view from where it is pushed, there are two UIViews related to each other (red and green). For case when it doesn't work it looks like this:

[image]

But for case where it works it looks like this:

[image]

In the second case, I simply remove leading constraint of the green view to the trailing constraint of the red view. But I need it there to make it fit to the view and without collapsing. How can I do it correctly?

How does it look in code when it works (using SnapKit for constraints)?

```
greenView.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
        maker.trailing.equalTo(-20)
        //            maker.leading.greaterThanOrEqualTo(redView.snp.trailing).offset(10)
        maker.centerY.equalTo(locationButton)
        maker.height.equalTo(locationButton.snp.height)
        maker.width.greaterThanOrEqualTo(100)
}
```

Comment: What happened when you didn't set the background color?

Comment: the same, nothing changes...‍♂️

Comment: I would try it with my own subclass of `UIViewController` and chat which functions are called.  What kind of view controller are you pushing from?  Are there VC navigation delegate methods implemented?

Comment: I updated the question. I know why it doesnt work, but I dont know how to fix it. Could you look at it?;)